# Creating a custom pipe in Angular 6 to return a value based on an array

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I'm creating a simple custom pipe which doesn't seem to work:

This is my code in the pipe which I created by the CLI:- (contain.pipe.ts)

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'contain'
})
export class ContainPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(likes: any, term: any): any {

    for (var i = 0; i < likes.length ; i++) {
        if (likes[i] === term) {
            return "liked";
        }else{
            return "";
        }
    }
  }

}
```

Here's my component simply trying to output liked or not:- (recipe.component.html)

```
<h2>{{ [1,12,3] | contain:12}}</h2>
```

It doesn't seem to output any data, even if it's true!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're close, but notice, that when you `return` something from `for` loop, you just stop it, not return every value. In your case the more proper way will be to create an empty array, and push necessary values to it, like this:

```
transform(likes: any, term: any): any {
    var liked = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < likes.length ; i++) {
        if (likes[i] === term) {
            liked.push(term);
        }
    }
    return liked;
}
```

Here I just push the `term` value, but you can modify this chunk for your needs. Here is a [**STACKBLITZ**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-blyabk?file=src/app/pipe.ts).

Comment: you are simply amazing, thank you, you got few minutes, im trying to pass an array in there like <h2>{{ arr$ | contain:recipe.id}}</h2> , but i seem to fail big time?

Comment: @MohamedGabr, sure, I'll help. Let me know, what are `arr$` and `recipe.id`? Or better fork my stackblitz and modify it, it will be much easier to help.

Comment: ok take a look here at recent-blog-recipes.component , i get the array from the API i created and it toke me so long to return it as an array, then im trying to compare each recipe.id with that array. https://github.com/Imohamedgabr/recipes-community

Comment: this is how it looks in the console (3) [1, 2, 12] , and its an array but it gives out this error when i compile "TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined
    at ContainPipe.push../src/app/contain.pipe.ts. " but seems to output fine when i output it like this {{arr$}} , it gives out the full array.

Comment: this is the path src/app/welcome/recent-blog-recipes/

Comment: @MohamedGabr, I don't see `arr$` in your component, may be it's the problem? It's in HTML, but not in component.

Comment: @MohamedGabr, how the `arr$` and `recipes$` data looks like? `arr$` is a single dimensional array like `[1,2,12]` and `recipes$` is an array of objects like `[{prop1: "random string", id: 1}, {prop1: "random string", id: 2}]`?

Comment: @MohamedGabr, here I tried to reconstruct your real case: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-anwtr4?file=src/app/app.component.html. Is it correct?

Comment: this seems right, really appreciate it , thank you <3 i will work on mine <3 so you think i have to declare my array like so? i fetch it from server and it seems right

Comment: @MohamedGabr you're welcome. Regarding the array, I've just hardcoded it for example, if you want to get it from server - it's OK, it's the usual case.

Comment: you are so awesome, i almost gave up on angular, thank you for being the best :)

Comment: Why not simply `return likes.filter(x => x === term)`?

Comment: @developer033, because I tried to improve existing code, not to suggest the shorter one. But yes, your example looks much more beautiful and clear, I agree.

Answer (score 3):

It is because, your code returns an empty string if it cannot find the term you are looking for at index 0.

Following loop starts at index 0, check the term if it is equal to current element. If it is, it returns `liked`, if it is not it returns an empty string. It does not iterate through the whole array.

```
for (var i = 0; i < likes.length ; i++) {
    if (likes[i] === term) {
        return "liked";
    } else{
        return "";
    }
}
```

Change your pipe to following

```
  transform(likes: any, term: any): any {
      return likes.indexOf(term) > -1 ? 'liked': '';
  }
```

Comment: you are simply amazing, thank you, you got few minutes, im trying to pass an array in there like <h2>{{ arr$ | contain:recipe.id}}</h2> , but i seem to fail big time?

Comment: @MohamedGabr is `arr$` in format of number array? what's it's content?

Comment: but how does this really iterates through all of element in likes? doesnt make sense

Comment: @MohamedGabr `indexOf` is a method of arrays. It returns the index of the item you pass into, otherwise returns -1.